# Is there a way to query Google ngrams for more than 10 substitutions?

Tags: database, google-api, cpu-word

I'm trying to get more than 10 results from google ngrams using wildcards. Here is an example:

```
hello *
```

It gives me a plot with 10 lines, but I'd like to have more. I know that the data is freely available but I have no idea how to use that so I was wondering if anyone made a program that uses the same database while giving more freedom in what to search for.